# redis collection atomic lpop all

Tags: java-8, redisclient

redis list, a producer keeps lpush. In another thread, consumers periodically take all out from the list, and categorize elements. Because the producer keeps pushing, so the taking-all-out must be done atomically. So is there an effective way to do this? **spring-data-redis** could be used.

```
// producer
getOpsForList.push(k, v);

// consumer
alist = range(k,0,-1); // take all out
alist.parallelStream() // during which a producer thread could push but I hope it is "blocked".
delete(k);  // list is now empty and push from producer is unblocked.
```

`multi` and `exec` does not achieve my goal, because it actually submits `lrange`, `lpush` and `delete` just in one transaction. So far, the only way I could think of, is keeping `lpop` and add returned into `alist` until list is empty.

**EDIT**, this is what I think:
when you want to be sure an operation is ran only once, using `watch`:

```
watch key
val = get key
val = val + 1
multi
set key val
exec
```

when you want to be not "interrupted" (not multithreading interrupt), and don't care how many times it runs, transaction (`multi` and `exec`) is enough.

```
multi
val = lrange key 0 -1
delete key
exec
```

`val` is still a list after it finishes, like what is said in [official-doc](https://redis.io/topics/transactions)

> All the commands in a transaction are serialized and executed
>   sequentially. It can never happen that a request issued by another
>   client is served in the middle of the execution of a Redis
>   transaction.

Beyond redis, I took the data operation `list.stream.parallelism` out, and the function now only focuses on the data getter, which is exactly like the last code paragraph. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A good example to illustrate how WATCH can be used to create new **atomic** operations otherwise not supported by Redis is to implement ZPOP, that is a command that pops the element with the lower score from a sorted set in an atomic way.

There is a implementation for `ZPOP` in documentation as below:

```
WATCH zset
element = ZRANGE zset 0 0
MULTI
ZREM zset element
EXEC
```

What you need to do is **repeat the operation above If EXEC fails (i.e. returns a Null reply)**. the producer operation `lpush` is atomic, so it needn't to use [watch](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#optimistic-locking-using-check-and-set) command. for example:

```
// consumer pesudo code
do {
  watch(k);
  transaction = multi();
  alist = transaction.range(k,0,-1); 
  transaction.delete(k);  
  status = get status of transaction.exec();
} while(status == null);

alist.parallelStream()
```

Comment: pls, put the opening text in a comment (if at all). SO, is no place for flirting, casanova ;)!

Comment: @holi-java watch would submit an execution when the watching target has not changed. While this is not exactly what I want. I wish when consumers accept all elements, producers's push operation could be blocked, and only recovered when consumers finish (i.e., after delete). But I will compare your solution with the lpop loop.

Comment: @holi-java producer pop randomly but quite often. spring-data-redis has `pushAll` so I am looking for a way to achieve `popAll`

Comment: @Tiina why does producer need to pop element out of list?

Comment: @Tiina if your reqiurement is pop all element from consumer you can set 2 keys one is `offset` starts at 0, another is `n` obtained by `llen`, then you can use pipeline to pop elements in each chunk(e.g: chunk size is 100) until `offset >= n`.

Comment: @Tiina hi, have you solved the problem? I'd like to know.

Comment: @holi-java please see EDIT part in my po.

Comment: @Tiina do you care about the order popped from the list? are there huge of elements popped from list?